# Validation.IsValid() does not validate Error Razor C#

Tags: c#, razor, razor-2

I am currently using the below code to validate that file uploaded is of a certain type. However, the code using Validation.IsValid seems to allow everything through and hence upload the code to the system.

Could someone please provide some assistance?

Using the @HTML.ValidationMessage I can see the error validation occurs (ie, only CSV are allowed)

Thank you

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Helpers;
    @{
        if(IsPost && @System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("EHM\\Domain Admins")) {
            if(Request.Files[0].ContentLength == 0){
                ModelState.AddError("fileUpload", "You must upload a file");

            } else {
                var allowedExtensions = new[]{".csv"};
                var extension = Path.GetExtension(Request.Files[0].FileName.ToLower());
                if(!allowedExtensions.Contains(extension)){
                    ModelState.AddError("fileUpload", "Only CSV are allowed");
                }
            }
            if(Validation.IsValid()) {
                var fileName = "";
                var fileSavePath = "";
                var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
                fileSavePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UploadedFiles/" + fileName);
                uploadedFile.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
            }
            else {
            <p class="bg-danger"> File has not been uploaded </p>
            }
        }

    }
```

edfef

```
@FileUpload.GetHtml(
    initialNumberOfFiles:1,
    allowMoreFilesToBeAdded:false,
    includeFormTag:true,
    uploadText:"Upload CSV only")
@Html.ValidationMessage("fileUpload")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Only CSV are allowed");
```

instead of

```
ModelState.AddError("fileUpload", "Only CSV are allowed");
```

to add the model error with an empty key and not to tie it to a specific property.

**Note**: Usually it's better to add the right property into your ViewModel and perform the validation for that property.

Comment: Hi mok, I've tried the above but I'm getting the following compile error. What dependencies do I need for it? CS1061: 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.ModelStateDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'AddModelError' and no extension method 'AddModelError' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.ModelStateDictionary' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Use `System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError`.